# upgrading sql version with ssis and ssrs on that server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

If I upgrade a SQL server 2016 STD to ENTERPRISE and that server has the following services installed: SSIS and SSRS
can I just upgrade the version of the SQL and it will automatically upgrade the SSIS and SSRS on that server or do I need to take additional steps?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the features installed as part of the one instance, yes, the [Edition Upgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/upgrade-to-a-different-edition-of-sql-server-setup?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=To%20upgrade%20to%20a%20different%20edition%20of%20SQL,your%20computer%2C%20restart%20before%20you%20continue.%20See%20More.) will upgrade them all.

Note, that for SQL Server 2017 and later Reporting Services is a separate installer, so it would be upgraded separately.

Comment: so no need to uninstall the services and then reinstall right?

Comment: Right.  An Edition Upgrade is not a reinstall.  It just unlocks the edition features by changing the activation key.

Comment: thanks highly appreciated.